# Changing directory with if else condition

Tags: bash, cd-command

Below is a small extract of my code for you to have a better visibilty on my problem. As each file in the directory enters the loop, the value of em is extracted from the filename and compared with the declared em values for the next actions to be executed.
After executing my code, I noticed that my first condition works but when it comes out from Em1 directory, the second condition is not more verified because I opened the Em2 directory and it was empty meanwhile I have files with em2 value. So i wish to know what is wrong

```
em1="first"
em2="second"
for file in *;
do
em=$( echo "$file" | awk -F'[.-]' '{print $1}' )
if [[ "$em" == "$em1" ]];
 then
   cd Em1                    #directory to execute action
   month_range               #function for action
   cd_ret                    #function to come back to current directory
elif [[ "$em" == "$em2" ]];
  then
   cd Em2
   month_range
   cd_ret
else
  echo "Nothing to do"
fi
done
```

Comment: Remove the `$` from the `for` statement (`for file in ...`). If that's not the problem, I'd recommend putting `set -x` before this section so it prints an execution trace -- inspect that and see if it differs from what you expect.

Comment: You're referring to a function called `cd_ret` which doesn't exist in the shown code. If it doesn't exist, that might be a problem. If you're just not showing it, then it's hard for any readers to check if there's a problem within it.

Comment: Ok thanks. The $ was a typing error

Answer (score 6):

You need to use a variable's name in the `for` loop header.  You used `$file` in your original question, i.e., the variable `file`'s value.

You are also doing things a bit complicated.  To run a command with a temporarily changed working directory, you may use a sub-shell.

```bsh
( cd Em1 && month_range )
```

The working directory outside of the sub-shell is not affected by the `cd` inside the sub-shell. It's unclear what your `cd_ret` function is doing, so that's another possible source of errors.  If you can't do it this way, for example, if `month_range` is setting variables that need to be visible in the original scope, then use

```bsh
cd Em1 && { month_range; cd -; }
```

The above would `cd` into `Em1`, run the `month_range` function, and `cd` back, assuming `month_range` does not do further calls to `cd`.  If `month_range` does use `cd`, then save the current working directory in a variable and use that instead.

```bsh
wd=$PWD; cd Em1 && { month_range; cd "$wd"; }
```

The above assumes that `month_range` does not change or unset the `wd` variable.

Your use of `awk` is problematic as filenames on Unix technically may contain newline characters.  It would be better to use a parameter substitution.

```bsh
em=${file%%[.-]*}
```

The above chops off the value `$file` at first `-` or `.` character and assigns the resulting string to the variable `em`.

This leaves you with the following:

```bsh
em1=first
em2=second

for file in *; do
        em=${file%%[.-]*}

        if [ "$em" = "$em1" ]; then
                ( cd Em1 && month_range )
        elif [ "$em" = "$em2" ]; then
                ( cd Em2 && month_range )
        else
                echo 'Nothing to do'
        fi
done
```

or

```bsh
em1=first
em2=second

for file in *; do
        em=${file%%[.-]*}

        case $em in
                "$em1") ( cd Em1 && month_range ) ;;
                "$em2") ( cd Em2 && month_range ) ;;
                *) echo 'Nothing to do'
        esac
done
```

or, without extracting `em` from `$file` at all,

```bsh
em1=first
em2=second

for file in *; do
        case $file in
                "$em1"[.-]*) ( cd Em1 && month_range ) ;;
                "$em2"[.-]*) ( cd Em2 && month_range ) ;;
                *) echo 'Nothing to do'
        esac
done
```

or using `bash` syntax,

```bsh
em1=first
em2=second

for file in *; do
        if [[ $file == "$em1"[.-]* ]]; then
                ( cd Em1 && month_range )
        elif [[ $file == "$em2"[.-]* ]]; then
                ( cd Em2 && month_range )
        else
                echo 'Nothing to do'
        fi
done
```

If this then does what you intend depends on the `month_range` function or script.

Comment: The code `cd Em1 && { month_range; cd -; }` actually works for me. It goes in the Em1 directory performs month range and comes back to the current working directory without having to use my function cd_ret and same for Em2. cd_ret was just useless.

Comment: @NgouabaRosalie What about the simpler `( cd Em1 && month_range )`? If `month_range` is a script or function that does not need to change the current environment (set variables etc.), then this would be simpler code.